# Why is $x^2\sin(1/x)$ not strictly differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am on Wikipedia reading on [strict differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_differentiability) and I don't particularly understand the example proving a function that is differentiable does not have to be strictly differentiable, where $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $f(0)=0$. How can we show this is differentiable directly using difference quotients. Also then how can we show it's not strictly differentiable using our difference quotients?

> The simplest setting in which strict differentiability can be considered, is that of a real-valued function defined on an interval $I$ of the real line. The function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is said strictly differentiable in a point $a \in I$ if
> $$
> \lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(a, a)} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
> $$
> exists, where $(x, y) \rightarrow(a, a)$ is to be considered as limit in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$, and of course requiring $x \neq y$.
> A strictly differentiable function is obviously differentiable, but the converse is wrong, as can be seen from the counter-example $f(x)=x^{2}$ sin $\frac{1}{x}, f(0)=0, x_{n}=\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi}, y_{n}=x_{n+1}$.
> One has however the equivalence of strict differentiability on an interval $I$, and being of differentiability class $C^{1}(I)$.
> [(Transcribed from Wikipedia screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtOG6.png)

so far I have;

To show $f(x)$ is differentiable, I would assume I'd use the statement that if $x^2$ is differentiable and $\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable (which can be shown by the difference quotients, then $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ is also differentiable?

Comment: $f'$ is not continuous at $0$, let $y \to x$ before $x\to 0$ you'll have $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?  Have you tried finding the limit along the sequence mentioned?

Comment: I don't know how to find the limit along the sequence, do I take f(x) as $x^2 sin(1/x))$, but then what is f(y)? and is our x and y in this case, $x_n$ and $y_n$, if so what is our a?

Comment: please define "strictly differentiable"

Comment: @zhw.: the given image contains a definition of *strictly differentiable*, but yes this should have been explicitly given in the post. A function $f:I\to\mathbb{R} $ defined on an interval $I$ is said to be strictly differentiable at $a\in I$ if the two variable limit $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, a)} \frac{f(x) - f(y)} {x-y} $$ exists.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. Is there any difference between strictly differentiable and continuously differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall negation of function limit definition.

$$
\text{if } \exists p_k, q_k\in\mathbb{R^n}:
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} p_k, q_k=x_0:
\lim_{{k\rightarrow \infty}} g(p_k) \neq \lim_{{k\rightarrow \infty}} g(q_k)
\Rightarrow \text{no limit}
$$

Let us use this fact to prove that the desired limit doesn't exist.

$$
\begin{multline}
\exists
p_k=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x_{2k}\\y_{2k}\end{smallmatrix}\right),
q_k=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x_{2k+1}\\y_{2k+1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\in \mathbb{R}^2:
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} p_k, q_k=
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right):\\
\frac{2}{\pi}=\lim_{{k\rightarrow \infty}} \frac{f(x_{2k})-f(y_{2k})}{x_{2k}-y_{2k}} \neq \lim_{{k\rightarrow \infty}}  \frac{f(x_{2k+1})-f(y_{2k+1})}{x_{2k+1}-y_{2k+1}}=-\frac{2}{\pi}
\end{multline}
$$

where $f(z) = z^2\sin\frac{1}{z}$, $x_n=\frac{1}{(n+1/2)pi}$ and $y_n=x_{n+1}$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0\\y \rightarrow 0}\cfrac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} - y^2\sin\frac{1}{y}}{x-y}
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{x_n^2\sin\frac{1}{x_n} - y_n^2\sin\frac{1}{y_n}}{x_n-y_n}\\
&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{\left(\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}\right)^2\sin(n+1/2)\pi - \left(\frac{1}{(n+3/2)\pi}\right)^2\sin(n+3/2)\pi}{\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}- \frac{1}{(n+3/2)\pi}}\\
&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{\left(\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}\right)^2(-1)^n - \left(\frac{1}{(n+3/2)\pi}\right)^2(-1)^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{(n+1/2)(n+3/2)\pi}}\\
&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\left(\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{(n+3/2)\pi}\right)^2\right](-1)^{n}(n+1/2)(n+3/2)\pi\\
&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2n^2+4n+5/2}{(n+1/2)^2(n+3/2)^2\pi^2}(-1)^{n}(n+1/2)(n+3/2)\pi\\
&=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^2+2n+5/4}{(n+1/2)(n+3/2)}\frac{(-2)^{n}}{\pi}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

It is clear to see, that

$$
\begin{aligned}
n = 2k &\rightarrow p_k \rightarrow\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cfrac{\sim 2n^2}{\sim \pi n^2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\\
n = 2k+1 &\rightarrow q_k \rightarrow\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} -\cfrac{\sim 2n^2}{\sim \pi n^2} = -\frac{2}{\pi}
\end{aligned}
$$

To sum up, $f$ is not strictly differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

More general result: Suppose $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $I,$ and $f'$ is discontinuous at some $x_0\in I.$ Then $f$ is not strictly differentiable on $I.$

Proof: Let $a_n$ be a sequence of distinct points converging to $x_0.$  By the MVT there exist $b_n$ between $x_0$ and $a_n$ such that

$$\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}=f'(b_n).$$

As $n\to \infty,$ we see $f'(b_n) \to f'(x_0).$ On the other hand, because $f'$ is discontinuous at $x_0,$ there exists a sequence $c_n\to x_0$ such that $f'(c_n)$ does not converge t0 $f'(x_0).$

Now find sequences $s_n,t_n\to x_0$ such that

$$\left | \frac{f(s_n)-f(t_n)}{s_n-t_n}-f'(b_n) \right |<1/n$$

and sequences $u_n,v_n\to x_0$ such that

$$\left | \frac{f(u_n)-f(v_n)}{u_n-v_n}-f'(c_n) \right |<1/n.$$

Both the sequences $(s_n,t_n),(u_n,v_n)$ converge to $(x_0,x_0).$ Consider the sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ obtained by putting these two sequences together. I.e., $(x_n,y_n)$ is the sequence

$$(s_1,t_1),(u_1,v_1),(s_2,t_2),(u_2,v_2), \dots $$

Then $(x_n,y_n)\to (x_0,x_0)$ and the corresponding difference quotients converge to $f'(x_0)$ through odd values of $n,$ but fail to converge to $f'(x_0)$ through even values of $n.$

Therefore $f$ is not strictly differentiable on $I.$

In our specific problem $f'$ is not continuous at $0,$ so this $f$ is not stricly differentiable on $\mathbb R$ by the general result.

Comment: "Because $f'$ is discontinuous at $x_0,$ there exist $L\ne M$ and sequences $a_n,b_n\to x_0$  such that $f'(a_n) \to L$ and $f'(b_n) \to M$": why is this? It's not true for discontinuous functions in general. So if it's true for derivatives (and I don't know that it is), it is a special result that can't just be assumed to be true.

Comment: @TonyK That's a good point. I edited by answer.

Comment: You haven't addressed my point at all.

Comment: @TonyK It's a shame you only get one downvote. I think I addressed your "true for derivatives" bit by referring to the well known Darboux property. What else do I need to address?

Comment: Why does the Darboux property imply what you claim that it implies? You say "From this it follows...", and I don't see that at all. Can you try to explain it please?

Comment: @TonyK   If $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x) = 1$ and $f'(x_0)=0,$ then $f'$ fails to have the intermediate value property in $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ for small $\delta >0.$

Comment: @TonyK: Perhaps you are aware of the fact that derivatives don't have jump discontinuity ie if $f'(a) $ and $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x) $ exist then they must be equal.

Comment: On the other hand +1 here. Wikipedia mentions that : $f$ is strictly differentiable on an interval $I$ if and only if $f$ is continously differentiable on $I$. The same conclusion does not hold locally for a single point $a$.

Comment: Your proof shows one direction that strictly differentiable functions on an interval are also continuously differentiable on that interval. The converse follows from mean value theorem.

Comment: I was asking about the bit after "From this it follows...", not the bit after "This follows from...": the existence of $L$ and $M$.

Comment: @TonyK I edited my answer. Hopefully this is better.

Comment: I think we can choose $(s_n,t_n)=(a_n,x_0)$, can't we? And $v_n=c_n$. Then it seems to work.